# How can we loop through all file names in a folder and chagce only some of the names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have files that look like this.

```
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI 03312002.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI 03312003.txt
etc.
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII 03312002.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII 03312003.txt
```

(2 of 2)

I would like to end up with this.

```
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC1 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC1 03312002.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC1 03312003.txt
etc.
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC2 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC2 03312002.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC2 03312003.txt
```

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
# rename certain filenames
import os
import glob

path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

# first list
before = [
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCEI',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCEII'
    ]

# second list
after = [
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC1',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC2',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCE1',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCE2'
    ]


for f in all_files: 
    for x in before:
        if x in f:
            print(x)
            print(f)
            os.rename(x, path + after)
```

Comment: I think you are adding incorrect values, `path+after` path is a string while your after is a list

Comment: Somehow I need to get the right item in the list named 'after'.  That's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: you want to rename files in a directory from Roman to non Roman?

Comment: As I look at it closer, my approach will work, because 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI' is in both 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI' and 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII'.  These are two separate and distinct files.  I want to merge files with similar names together, but some files names are too similar, yet the contents of these two files are very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`. This works under the assumption that your `after` list has the equivalent name for the one in `before`. If this assumption is not possible then you can not use `zip`.

```
import os

path = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\'

# first list
before = [
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCEI',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCEII'
    ]

# second list
after = [
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC1',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC2',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCE1',
     'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCE2'
    ]


for before_name, after_name in zip(before, after):
    os.rename(path + before_name, path + after_name)
```

Comment: That almost works, but path+after_name is missing the last part: 03312001.txt

Comment: I have over 3000 files in my folder.  I can't add the extensions for all of them, that's why I want to loop through everything in the folder, and change just the ones I'm showing here.  Even with these four types, there are hundreds and hundreds of files with dates in the names.  Thanks.

Comment: I understand this now, so you have many files with different extensions but the "before" name is a common name in all files, is that it?

Comment: can you paste the output for `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))` in pastebin or something so I can run locally and try what I think might work?

Comment: That gives me this:

 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB 12312018(1 of 2).txt',
 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB 12312018(2 of 2).txt',
 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB 12312019(1 of 2).txt',
 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCB 12312019(2 of 2).txt',
 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI 03312001.txt',
 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI 03312002.txt',
 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCI 03312003.txt',
etc., etc., etc.

Comment: python_user, when I run your code, I get this error:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCCII' -> 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Downloads\\FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RCC2'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you need the full file name, with the extension too.

Comment: @ python_user, I ended up going with your solution.  I got the last 13 characters of the string using this method: string = f[-13:].  Now, this line of code works fin: os.rename(f, path + a + string)

Comment: sorry I wanted to get back but I got side tracked, glad to know you had it fixed @ASH

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import glob
##create int number from roman##
def roman_to_int( s):
    rom_val = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 
    'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
    int_val = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i > 0 and rom_val[s[i]] > rom_val[s[i - 1]]:
            int_val += rom_val[s[i]] - 2 * rom_val[s[i - 1]]
        else:
            int_val += rom_val[s[i]]
    return int_val
#set the path and get the files
path = '/home/jana/Workshop/convert roman/files/'
all_files = os.listdir(path)
files_name = []
for item in all_files:
    nam = item.split() 
    int_val = roman_to_int(nam[4][3:])
    nam[4] = nam[4][:3]+str(int_val)
    files_name.append(" ".join(nam))
    print(files_name)
##rename the file
for (before , after) in zip(all_files, files_name):
    path_name = path+before
    path_name_2 = path+after
    os.rename(path_name,path_name_2)
#this will work
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a little more explanation to why your answer works.